# AWS S3: Cost of listing all object versions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

In the scenario of listing all versions of an object using its key as a prefix:

```py
import boto3

bucket = 'bucket name'
key = 'key'
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
versions = s3.Bucket(bucket).object_versions.filter(Prefix=key)

for version in versions:
    obj = version.get()
    print(obj.get('VersionId'), obj.get('ContentLength'), obj.get('LastModified'))
```

Do I get charged only for listing the objects that are matching the prefix?

If so, is each object/version listed treated as a separate list request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, each object/version listed is *not* treated as a separate list request. You're only paying for the API requests to S3 (at something like $0.005 per 1000 API requests). A single API request will return many (up to 1000) objects/versions that match the indicated prefix. The prefix filtering itself happens server-side in S3.

The way to get a handle on this is to understand that AWS SDK calls ultimately result in API requests to AWS service endpoints e.g. [S3 APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html). What you need to do is work out how your SDK client requests map to the underlying API requests to determine what is likely happening.

If your request is a simple 'list objects in my bucket' case, the boto3 SDK is going to make one or more [ListObjectsV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) API calls. I say "or more" because the SDK may need to make more than one API request because API requests typically yield a maximum number of results (e.g. 1000 objects in a ListObjectsV2 response). If there are 2500 objects in the bucket, for example, then three ListObjectsV2 requests would need to be made to the S3 API.

If your request is 'list objects in my bucket with a given prefix', then you need to know what capabilities are present on the [ListObjectsV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) API call. Importantly, `prefix` is one of the parameters. This is how you know that S3 itself is doing the filtering on your supplied prefix (where you have indicated `.filter(Prefix=key)` in your code). If this were not a feature of the underlying S3 API, then your SDK (boto3 etc.) would be the one doing the filtering on prefix and that would be a much more expensive and vastly slower operation, because the SDK would have to list *all* objects, potentially resulting in many more LIST requests, and filter them client-side. Note: the ListObjectVersions API is similar to ListObjectsV2  in this regard and both support `prefix`.

Also, note that `VersionId`, `Size`, and `LastModifed` are all attributes that appear in the [ListObjectVersions response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectVersions.html#API_ListObjectVersions_ResponseSyntax), so no further API requests are needed to fetch this information.

So, in your case, assuming that there are fewer than 1000 object versions that match your indicated prefix, I believe that this equates to one S3 API request to ListObjectVersions (and this is considered a LIST request rather than a GET request for billing afaik, even though it is a GET HTTP request to `https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/?versions` under the covers).